# ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float' but got 'double' while using kmeans

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to create histograms and save them to .csv file, by extrating the SURF features and clustering them using MiniKbatchMeans. I have a dataset with images of sign languages.
I created dataset of sign language images from 0-9 and a to z, i want to create histogram and consequently save it as .csv file. I am successful using the surf feature but cant get the whole code to work
here is my code:

```
n_classes=36
clustering_factor=6

import tensorflow as tf

# Detect hardware
try:
  tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()  # TPU detection
  print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])
except ValueError:
  raise BaseException('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the previous cell in this notebook for instructions!')

tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)

# Implementing Bag of Features Model

def surf_features(images):
  surf_descriptors_class_by_class={}
  surf_descriptors_list=[]
  surf=cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
  for key,value in images.items():
    print(key, "Started")
    features=[]
    for img in value:
      kp,desc=surf.detectAndCompute(img,None)
      surf_descriptors_list.extend(desc)
      features.append(desc)
    surf_descriptors_class_by_class[key]=features
    print(key," Completed!")
  return [surf_descriptors_list,surf_descriptors_class_by_class]

# Creating a visual dictionary using only the train dataset 
# K-means clustering alogo takes only 2 parameters which are number of clusters (k) and descrpitors list
# It reurn an array which holds central points

def minibatchkmeans(k, descriptors_list):
  kmeans=MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k)
  print("MiniBatchKMeans Initialized!")
  kmeans.fit(descriptors_list)
  print("Clusters Created!")
  visual_words=kmeans.cluster_centers_
  return visual_words, kmeans

# Loading train images into dictionaries which holds all images category by category

def load_images_by_category(folder):
  images={}
  for label in os.listdir(folder):
    print(label," started")
    category=[]
    path=folder+'/'+label
    for image in os.listdir(path):
      img=cv2.imread(path+'/'+image)
      #new_img=cv2.resize(img,(128,128))
      if img is not None:
        category.append(img)
    images[label]=category
    print(label, "ended")
  return images

# Creating histograms for train images

# Function takes 2 parameters. The first one is a dictionary that holds the descriptors that are separated class by class 
# And the second parameter is the clustered model
# Returns a dictionary that holds the histograms for each images that are separated class by class. 

def create_histogram(all_descs,kmeans):
  features_dict={}
  for key,value in all_descs.items():
    print(key," Started!")
    category=[]
    for desc in value:
      raw_words=kmeans.predict(desc)
      hist = np.array(np.bincount(raw_words,minlength=n_classes*clustering_factor),dtype=np.double)
      category.append(hist)
    features_dict[key]=category
    print(key," Completed!")
  return features_dict

train_folder='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/ISL Datasets/Train-Test/Train'

# Load train images
train_images=load_images_by_category(train_folder)
#print(len(train_images))

#print(len(train_images['a'][0][0]))

#Extracting surf features from each image stored in train_images list

surfs=surf_features(train_images)
all_train_descriptors=surfs[0]
train_descriptors_by_class=surfs[1]

#print(len(surfs[0]))
#print(len(surfs[1]['0'][1]))

# Calling MiniBatchkmeans function and getting central points
visual_words,kmeans=minibatchkmeans(n_classes*clustering_factor,all_train_descriptors)


# Calling create_histogram and getting histogram for each image
bows_train=create_histogram(train_descriptors_by_class,kmeans)

#print((bows_train['a'][0][1]))

# Saving .csv file
import csv
loc='/content/gdrive/MyDrive/ISL Datasets/cnn files/train.csv'
with open(loc,'w',newline='') as file:
  writer=csv.writer(file)
  header=[]
  for i in range (1,n_classes*clustering_factor):
    header.append(str('pixel')+str(i))
  header.append('Label')
  writer.writerow(header)
  count=0
  for label in bows_train:
     # print(len(bows_train[label]))
    for i in range(len(bows_train[label])):
      list=[]
      for j in range(150):
        list.append(bows_train[label][i][j])
      list.append(label)
      writer.writerow(list)
```

however i get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b30a5a61b010> in <module>()
    103 
    104 # Calling create_histogram and getting histogram for each image
--> 105 bows_train=create_histogram(train_descriptors_by_class,kmeans)
    106 
    107 #print((bows_train['a'][0][1]))

3 frames
<ipython-input-3-b30a5a61b010> in create_histogram(all_descs, kmeans)
     74     category=[]
     75     for desc in value:
---> 76       raw_words=kmeans.predict(desc)
     77       hist = np.array(np.bincount(raw_words,minlength=n_classes*clustering_factor),dtype=np.double)
     78       category.append(hist)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in predict(self, X, sample_weight)
   2154             x_squared_norms,
   2155             self.cluster_centers_,
-> 2156             n_threads=self._n_threads,
   2157         )
   2158 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in _labels_inertia_threadpool_limit(X, sample_weight, x_squared_norms, centers, n_threads)
    755     with threadpool_limits(limits=1, user_api="blas"):
    756         labels, inertia = _labels_inertia(
--> 757             X, sample_weight, x_squared_norms, centers, n_threads
    758         )
    759 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/cluster/_kmeans.py in _labels_inertia(X, sample_weight, x_squared_norms, centers, n_threads)
    741         center_shift,
    742         n_threads,
--> 743         update_centers=False,
    744     )
    745 

sklearn/cluster/_k_means_lloyd.pyx in sklearn.cluster._k_means_lloyd.lloyd_iter_chunked_dense()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'float' but got 'double'
```

Comment: try to convert desc to floats with `desc = desc.astype(float)` before calling `raw_words=kmeans.predict(desc)` , this worked in my case